# transofrm third-order linear ode with given restrictions to dy/dx = f(x)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

having an ode Ay'''(x) + By''(x) + Cy'(x) + Dy(x) = E. A-E are known constants, it's also given y''(0) = y'(0) = y(0) = 0. And y(x) is a polynome. How do i transofrm this ode to y'(x) = f(x)?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: May be you want transform to system of three equations?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.